# How to log data during postinstall

Tags: node.js, npm

I am running a script in node.js with postinstall. Everything works fine, but I am unable to log data. Is it possible to log data in this script? It looks like console.log() does not work during postinstall or do I miss something?

I defined the script in the package.json like this:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node ./folder/my_script.js"
  },
```

Comment: can you please share code where you are doing logs, if you are getting some errors please share that too